# Map between custom wrapper and String with Mapstruct

Tags: mapstruct

I'm using Mapstruct 1.5.5.Final. We have a number of custom classes, which are essentially just wrappers around a `String`. For example:

```java
public class PortfolioId {

    private final String id;

    public PortfolioId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I want to have a Mapstruct mapper for that class, so I tried to create something like this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface PortfolioIdMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "portfolioId", target = "id")
    PortfolioId toPortfolioId(String portfolioId);


    String fromPortfolioId(PortfolioId portfolioId);
}
```

And got this mapper generated:

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-05-30T16:20:35+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 17.0.6 (Amazon.com Inc.)"
)
public class PortfolioIdMapperImpl implements PortfolioIdMapper {

    @Override
    public PortfolioId toPortfolioId(String portfolioId) {
        if ( portfolioId == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String id = null;

        id = portfolioId;

        PortfolioId portfolioId1 = new PortfolioId( id );

        return portfolioId1;
    }

    @Override
    public String fromPortfolioId(PortfolioId portfolioId) {
        if ( portfolioId == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String string = new String();

        return string;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the generated `fromPortfolioId` method just returns an empty string back. Is there  any way to fix this? I assume, I also need to add a `@Mapping` annotation there, but what should I use as a `target`? Having something like this:

```java
@Mapping(source = "id", target = "value")
String fromPortfolioId(PortfolioId portfolioId);
```

Gives me a compilation error:

```
Unknown property "value" in result type String. Did you mean "empty"?
```

Leaving the target empty:

```java
@Mapping(source = "id", target = "")
String fromPortfolioId(PortfolioId portfolioId);
```

gives the same:

```
Unknown property "" in result type String. Did you mean "empty"?
```

Comment: I actually just found something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111998/mapstruct-how-to-construct-a-string-from-an-objects-property-in-mapstruct?rq=2 and here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/584, so it looks like it's not really possible... The suggested solution is to create that code manually, which is really not nice when there are a lot of classes like that and they are all nullable.